# Finding azimuths/bearings between many consecutive points in ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, azimuth, bearing

I have a ton of consecutive points and I need to know the bearing between each of them (a to b, b to c, c to d,etc).  Ultimately, I will convert the numbers (bearings, azimuths?) to directions: N, NE, NNE, NNW,etc.

I have found a python script for use in the field calculator that comes close to doing this but it returns angles:
https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/dan_patterson/2016/09/01/distance-calculations-using-the-field-calculator

Another option would be a script that can convert the angles returned by the above script to bearings/azimuths. For instance, the above script returns -90 rather than 270 for due west.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  Have you attempted to modify the script to output what you require?  Please [edit] your question to include a snippet of what you've tried, and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.4. No, I haven't tried modifying anything because  I do not know Python or scripting in general.  Dan Patterson has a script for returning directions from azimuths but he doesn't have a script for calculating azimuths between consecutive points.

Comment: You can always add/subtract 360 to change the sign. From there, it's simple to convert to cardinal directions.

Comment: Try tool Generate near table

Answer (score 1):

This will do it on a plane surface

```
import math
from itertools import cycle
def angle_wrt_x(B,A):
    ax, ay = A
    bx, by = B
    b = math.degrees(math.atan2(ax-bx,ay-by))
    if b < 0:
        b+=360
    elif b >= 360:
        b-=360
    return b

firstPoint = (0,0)
secondPoint = (1,1)

coord_pairs = [(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)]

listcycle = cycle(coord_pairs)

for firstPoint in coord_pairs:
    secondPoint = listcycle.next()
    print firstPoint,secondPoint, angle_wrt_x(firstPoint,secondPoint)
```

Returns

```
(0, 0) (0, 1) 0.0
(0, 1) (1, 1) 90.0
(1, 1) (1, 0) 180.0
(1, 0) (0, 0) 270.0
```

Add this def, you'll need to finish it off for all other regions on the compass

```
def compassPoints(b):
    if b > 348.75 or b <= 11.25:
        compB = 'N'
    elif 11.25 < b <= 33.75:
        compB ='NNE'
    elif 33.75 < b <= 56.25:
        compB = 'NE'
    #continue this pattern for the rest of them....

   return compB
```

then call it with

```
for firstPoint in coord_pairs:
    secondPoint = listcycle.next()
    b = angle_wrt_x(firstPoint,secondPoint)
    print compassPoints(b)
```

Comment: To use it I need it to return NE, SE, NW, SW, etc and also NNW, NNE, SSE, SSW etc.  Thanks for your help